# Merging two json in one in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, json

I have two json which I want to merge and create one json

json1

```
{
  id: "99",
  name: "ABC",
  salary: "1000",
  depat : "AB"
}

var json2 = '{section:"' + sectionval + '"}';
```

expected json

```
{
  id: "99",
  name: "ABC",
  salary: "1000",
  depat : "AB"
  section: "sectionb"
}
```

I have tried

```
let finalop = Object.assign(json1, json2);
```

but this will consider each character from json 2 as separate

I even tried

```
var finalop = {...json1, ...json2}
```

but this is also not working

I want to know what is correct function for this

Comment: is this obj is correct **var json2 ='{section:"' + sectionval + '"}';**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the below code. Working fine for me.

```
let json1 = {
   id: "99",
   name: "ABC",
   salary: "1000",
   depat : "AB"
};

let sectionval = 'sectionb';
let json2 = { section: sectionval};
let finalop = { ...json1, ...json2};

console.log(finalop);
```

**Output:**

```
{id: "99", name: "ABC", salary: "1000", depat: "AB", section: "sectionb"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the double quotes in json2.

```
var json2 ='{"section":"' + sectionval + '"}';
```

See the below output.

```js
var sectionval = 'sectionb';
var json2 ='{"section":"' + sectionval + '"}';

var json1 = {
  id: "99",
  name: "ABC",
  salary: "1000",
  depat : "AB"
};

var output = {...json1, ...JSON.parse(json2)};

console.log(output)
```

you can also change you json2 like this.

```
var json2 = { section: sectionval };
```

```js
var sectionval = 'sectionb';
var json2 = { section: sectionval };

var json1 = {
  id: "99",
  name: "ABC",
  salary: "1000",
  depat : "AB"
};

var output = {...json1, ...json2};

console.log(output)
```